# How can I prevent mobs from spawning in unlit places?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In vanilla minecraft mobs don't spawn if the light level of the block is 9 or above. However, I often don't want to fully lit all my structures. I might want a courtyard or a cellar that isn't fully lit. Also controllable light systems with redstone are a lot of fun to make, but I can never turn the lights off in fear of spawning mobs.

Is there a mod or another solution to have both unlit places and no mobs around? Maybe some kind of block that prevents mobs from spawning within a radius.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not counting mods, the best way I know of is to make sure the area you're "protecting" has a floor made of blocks which don't allow mob spawning.

Any [transparent block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Opaque#Types_of_transparent_blocks) will do the trick, such as glass or snow, and in your case maybe [Slabs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slab) will be most suitable.

For more in-depth information about spawning and spawn conditions, check the wiki:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Mob_Spawning

Comment: I never knew slabs didn't allow spawning on top of them. That will work in most places. Still hoping for a solution for floors that cannot be made out of slabs or other transparent blocks, but as there doesn't seem to be any, I will accept this answer.

Comment: hmm this make me curious, If you place 2 slabs on top of each-other do they still allow mob spawning? or do they count as a solid block and the rule does not apply?

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma They count as a solid block. In fact, the "top" half of a slab, even by itself, counts as a spawnable surface too.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent mob spawning by accumulating 96 zombies in your chunk and no other mobs will spawn as 96 mobs is the mob cap. Just make sure that they don't despawn while you are not around by giving them something to hold such as a pumpkin.

Comment: Zombies holding stuff don't despawn?

Comment: Yes, mobs holding items of any kind will not despawn

Answer (score 0):

The way to keep mobs from spawning in unlit places is by putting slabs, levers, or water for the floors.

Thanks for reading this if you  found  this helpful than your welcome!

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! While this is a fine and adequate answer, all of the information present has already been posted in another answer. If you have any other information to add (pertaining to the topic of course), feel free to edit your post and add that information in.

Answer (score 0):

The command **/gamerule doMobSpawning false** will prevent mobs from spawning without player help. Use **/gamerule doMobSpawning true** to turn it back on.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can just set your difficulty to peaceful? Mybe you can just type /difficulty peaceful and then only in that world it'll be peaceful. So mobs won't spawn and in other worlds they will spawn.